# Multiply elements in second column according to labels in the first

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I'm working in Matlab. 
I have a two-dimensional matrix with two columns. Lets consider elements in the first column as labels. Labels may be repeated.

How to multiply all elements in the second column for every label?

Example:

```
matrix = [1,3,3,1,5; 2,3,7,8,3]'
```

I need to get:

```
a = [1,3,5; 16,21,3]'
```

Can you help me with doing it **without** `for-while` cycles?

Comment: Why aren't you allow to use a `for`-loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without loops using [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html?searchHighlight=accumarray) and the `prod` function:

```
clear
clc


matrix = [1,3,3,1,5; 2,3,7,8,3]';

A = unique(matrix,'rows');

group = A(:,1);

data = A(:,2);

indices = [group ones(size(group))];

prods = accumarray(indices, data,[],@prod); %// As mentionned by @Daniel. My previous answer had a function handle but there is no need for that here since prod is already defined in Matlab.

a = nonzeros(prods)

Out = [unique(group) a]

Out =

     1    16
     3    21
     5     3
```

Check Lauren blog's post [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/02/20/under-appreciated-accumarray/), accumarray is quite interesting and powerful!

Answer (score 7):

I would use `accumarray`. The preprocessing with `unique` assigns integer indices 1:n to the values in the first row, which allow `accumarray` to work without creating unnecessary bins for 2 and 4. It also enables the support for negative numbers and floats.

```
[ulable,~,uindex]=unique(matrix(:,1))
r=accumarray(uindex,matrix(:,2),[],@prod)
r=[ulable,r]
```

/You can also use splitapply:

```
[ulable,~,uindex]=unique(matrix(:,1))
r=splitapply(@prod,matrix(:,2),uindex)
r=[ulable,r]
```

Comment: Nice use of accumarray and much cleaner than my solution +1 :)

Comment: `unique`+`accumarray` FTW! They make a great team.  Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, I'm sure it can be improved...

```
unValues = unique(matrix(:,1));
bb = ones(size(unValues));

for ii = 1:length(unValues)
    bb(ii) = bb(ii)*prod(matrix(matrix(:, 1) == unValues(ii), 2));
end

a = [unValues bb];
```