# Perform an operation on indexed/grouped elements of an array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

This seems to be a simple question, but useful for many applications nonetheless. Given a a two column array in Matlab:

```
x(:,1) = [1 1 1 2 2 2 5 5 8 8 8 8];
x(:,2) = rand(1,12);
```

How can an operation like `min()` be performed on all elements with the same `x(:,1)`, without a loop? For instance, if the minimum element is desired, the resulting vector is `y` (using my ouput from `rand(1,12)`.

```
y = [1 2 5 8 ; .3 .034 .51 .21];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html)

Comment: @CrisLuengo, That command did the trick. Could you possibly answer the question so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Same question, just asking for prod instead of min: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27783084/2732801

Comment: Similar, but ```splitapply``` not addressed there.

Comment: @OliverAmundsen: Now it is. For this application, `splitapply` and `accumarray` can be used interchangeably. Both are good ways to solve this question.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for updating your answer there, I still believe that some people will find useful the formulation of this specific question!

Comment: Yes, the formulation of this question is useful. But it's not useful to post the same answer in two questions. The duplicate redirection solves this issue. People might find this question by googling, and will then be redirected to Daniel's answer in the other question. We like good duplicate questions here on SO, it will not be deleted.